# Multiple character inputs for single physical press

Tags: c#, com-interop, awesomium

I am attempting to process the windows messages for keyboard events and pass them into an awesomium webview. The webview has native handling for windows events, but the host program must capture them, and send them on.

I am using .net and the com interop to capture and send on the messages. The key events are passed on to the best of my knowledge, but the input is variable. For example, there are varying numbers of characters being entered in a text box for a single press.

Here is a sample of the code I am using (credit to Sekhat on the awesomium site) :

```
        private void CreateHook()
        {

            uint threadId = Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);

            //hHook = Win32.SetWindowsHookEx(Win32.HookType.WH_CALLWNDPROC, wndProcDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, threadId);
            hHook = Win32.SetWindowsHookEx(Win32.HookType.WH_GETMESSAGE, wndProcDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, threadId);

        }

        private int WndProcHook(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref Win32.Message lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                Win32.TranslateMessage(ref lParam); 
                WndProc(ref lParam);
            }

            return Win32.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
        }

        wndProcDelegate = WndProcHook;
```

Am I handling the events wrong, leading to the variable number of inputs? I beleive the relevant parts are above, but can post the rest if needed.

On a side note, when I use WH_KEYBOARD instead of WH_GETMESSAGE an AccessViolationException is thrown. Is the KEYBOARD event the right one to use? Thank you for any assistance.

EDIT: I have done some further investigation and discovered that multiple messages of type 0x102 (WM_CHAR) are being passed to my program. The number passed matches the number of characters that awesomium is then outputting. Should I limit this to only the first message? While this may work, I would still like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to devise a working fix:

```
if (message.msg == 256)
{
    accept = true;
}
if (accept && message.msg == 258)
{
    view.InjectKeyboardEventWin((int)message.msg, (int)message.wparam, (int)message.lparam);
    accept = false;
}
if (message.msg != 258)
{
    view.InjectKeyboardEventWin((int)message.msg, (int)message.wparam, (int)message.lparam);
}
```

This code checks for a key down, and if found, set accept to true. The char message is only processed if a key down has been received since the last one. This allows text entry, while preserving other messages. I am still interested in discovering the root cause however.